# not in ruby test/unit assertions

Tags: ruby

This does not work as I expect:

```
class FooTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_foo
      assert(not true)
   end
end
```

I expected a failing test, instead I get:

```
SyntaxError: ./test.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected kNOT
assert(not true)
```

Explanations?

Comment: Surprisingly, it works using `!`. I am using jruby 1.6.1.

Comment: Not surprising; `not` is not a unary operator, but `!` is. See a [quick ref of operators and precedence](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#23).

Comment: Dave: could you elaborate? What are the other arguments for the `not` operator?

Comment: Other arguments? Same as `&&`, but with much lower precedence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you are getting a syntax error is, well, because it's a syntax error: `and`, `or` and `not` aren't allowed in an argument list.

There has been a lengthy discussion about this on the ruby-talk mailinglist, where it was explained exactly *why* that is the case, but *my* interpretation basically is "we couldn't figure out how to do it in `yacc` and switching to a better parser generator was too much work, so we just decided to make it illegal instead".

Comment: @LBg: That's not the one I meant, but it's even better because it's an actual bug report, not just an idle discussion.

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to Jörg answer.
You may use:

```
class FooTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_foo
      assert(! true)
      assert( (not true))
   end
end
```